# Cakephp 1.3 url rewriting

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-1.3, pretty-urls

I have my cakephp 1.3 console installed on hostgator server using SSH. I baked an app and everything seems to be working fine, but when I go to the app http://www.domain.com/app everything is green except for the second one which states:

```
    URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.
    1. Help me configure it
    2. I don't / can't use URL rewriting
```

and this is in red. I tried to follow guide, but I don't want to muck anything up if there is a simple solution. Help would greatly be appreciated.

#

I think it may be a bug in cakephp 1.3... not sure though yet still looking.

Comment: I downgraded to version 1.3.9 and it works fine now. I guess it was just a bug in latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional check isn't in the code in /cake/libs/views/pages/home.ctp - this was a bug or oversight in the recent release.

If you copy that file to your /app/views/pages/home.ctp you can easily enough edit the block that makes that check out of the default homepage. Or better yet, you can simply create your own custom home.ctp.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer. I'm glad to know it was just a simple error and wouldn't have affected my installations.